# didBeginContact not called swift3 Xcode8

Tags: swift3, xcode8

i have a Problem with the method didBeginContact. I have a ball and a wall.
The collision of both objects works fine. If both objects collide, they change their position but the method didBeginContact is not called.

```
// constants.swift
...

let ballCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0 
let wallCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

...

// Physics balls (ball.swift)
...

init() {
  let size = CGSize(width: 32, height: 44)
  loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: size)
}

func loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: CGSize){
 physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
 physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
 physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
 physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
}

...

// Physics wall (wall.swift)
...

init() {
  let size = CGSize(width: 32, height: 44)
  loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: size)
}

func loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: CGSize){
 physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
 physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
 physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
}

...

// GameScene (gameScene.swift)
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate { 
...
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
   physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
 }
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){
  print("didBeginContact called")
 }
}
```

Has anybody any idea? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by changing

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)

to

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)